# Is there a better Play unit test runner that allows you to run individual tests?

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

Is there some way to run individual tests (not just test classes) in Play 1.x?

The bundled test runner will only let you select test classes.

Comment: Can't you run them from your IDE?

Comment: @dantuch - I'd like to, but it doesn't work out of the box. There are two kinds of test classes here : those that extend Play's UnitTest class (for which it might be better to run them from Play's test runner, because it doesn't involve creating a new Play instance each time), and those that don't extend this class (for which it should indeed just work from the IDE ... haven't tried writing those in a while)